# Wordpress and flowplayer vast advert

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, flowplayer, vast

I have problem with flowplayer on wordpress. I know it been plugin for adsense add but my client need use they own ads. I found plugin who named VAST  but I don't know how I'm using this plugin in wordpress.

Additionaly I have xml file where I get data for ads, for example:

```
<VAST version="2.0">

<Ad id="1" sequence="1">
    <InLine>
      <AdSystem version="2.0">....</AdSystem>
      <AdTitle></AdTitle>
      <Impression></Impression>
      <Creatives>
        <Creative id="14">
          <Linear>
            <Duration>.....</Duration>
           <TrackingEvents>
              <Tracking event=.....
              <Tracking ev......
              <Tracking even....
              <Tracking eve...
              <Tracking even....
              <Tracking event...
              <Tracking ev...
          <Tracking eve...
              <Tracking ev...
              <Tracking e...
          <Tracking eve...
          <Tracking eve...
              <Trackin...
          <Tracking event...
          <Tracking even...
              <Tracking even...
            </TrackingEvents>
            <VideoClicks>
              <ClickThrough>...</ClickThrough>
            </VideoClicks>
            <MediaFiles>
              <MediaFile id="1" delivery="progressive" type="video/mp4" bitrate="466" width="956" height="538">
              <![CDATA[...]]>
              </MediaFile>
              <MediaFile id="2" delivery="progressive" type="video/webm" bitrate="466" width="956" height="538">
              <![CDATA[...]]>
              </MediaFile>
              <MediaFile id="3" delivery="progressive" type="video/x-flv" bitrate="466" width="956" height="538">
              <![CDATA[...]]>
              </MediaFile>
           </MediaFiles>
          </Linear>
        </Creative>
      </Creatives>
    </InLine>
  </Ad>
</VAST>
```

1. Is this possible?
2. How to do this? What file I need to edit? Where to add js file from flowplayer.org?

And Yes, I read documentation but, that documentation for VAST don't have version for wordpress such like adwords plugin for wordpress.
Thanks :)

Comment: Could you provide more information in where you are stuck? Do you have any error? etc...

Comment: I read this https://flowplayer.org/vast/ and view examples on this page but in wordpress flowplayer setting we can setup adsense ad but I don't know how add vast plugin for my videos. On flowplayer website we see url address for required library but when I go to source flowplayer in wordpress I see this js file is included but their source url view like $config['vast']. Where I configure this variable ? And whats next ?

Answer (score 0):

That is generic ads. VAST 2.0 is probably commonly used still now. For technology related sites (or like that) Kaltura player works with DFP. We bypass complexity of backend setup of Ad Server with DFP. Kaltura has support for new VPAID/VAST 3.0. they do have WP Plugin ([see on WordPress repo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-video-pack/)). Here are resources on Kaltura and Generic Ads --

1. [Generic Ads](https://knowledge.kaltura.com/kaltura%E2%80%99s-generic-ads-player-plugin-vast)
2. [Server side ads](http://corp.kaltura.com/products/core-platform/server-side-ad-insertion)
3. [Example](http://player.kaltura.com/modules/KalturaSupport/tests/AdPodsVast3.html)

Although you probably need not to know about Google Ads, still in common cases, DFP is used to serve in house Ads and actually will give idea about Ad serving  --

- [Video technology partners](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/186110) (gives idea about compatibility of their recognised players)
- [DFP creative hosting and transcoding](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/6391192?hl=en&ref_topic=4419887) (for ordinary need DFP is enough good)

Even simple problem with MIME type, cross origin can break the whole stuff.